# Bitcoin node filled the hard disk and now ubuntu won't boot up properly

Tags: boot, disk, acpi, bitcoin

I previously accidentally synced my bitcoin node to my harddisk with insufficient space (https://community.umbrel.com/t/how-to-stop-bitcoin-core-sync-mid-sync/15183?u=james_nakamoto). I didn't know how to stop it so I just let it run. It crashed, and now I can't even turn on my computer. When I try to boot up Ubuntu this is the error message [image] I'm a complete noob... Help????

Comment: You should be able to boot a live USB, and free up some space on your main disk.